# Suppress maven dependency version suffix in local repository

Tags: maven, crystal-reports

I have a Spring Boot project that uses SAP Crystal Reports.  CR is not published in Maven Central. I imported all of the CR jar files into my Maven local repository.  In my projects the jars have the version appended to the jar file name. For one jar file, this causes a runtime error.  How can I have that jar not have the appended Maven version?

Comment: The format in the local repository can't be changed.

Comment: I cannot imagine that the format of a jar in the local repository matters much. You don't run jars from the local repository.

Comment: The jar is for a licensed Bar Code font.  When maven appends a version number to the jar, I get runtime errors in the deployed application when the CR report is exported to a PDF with a bat code.

Comment: Can the local repository import be run without a version parameter?

Comment: You can remove the version numbers in the WAR or EAR that you build, but not in the local repository.

Comment: This is an XY-problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my workaround hack.

The Jar is question is never directly referenced by my project code, it is a runtime library of the Crystal Reports java runtime.  I do not need it in the classpath at build time, just in the deployed file built by maven.

My Spring Boot project is deployed as a WAR file so I need to structure my Eclipse Maven project so that the Jar is placed in WEB-INF/lib as a plain web app resource.  I do not specify the jar as a maven dependency.

It's a hack because the jar file IS a dependency and SHOULD be specified as a maven project dependency in the pom.xml.

This solves my immediate  problem.
I blame SAP for not considering Maven for their Crystal Reports Java runtime.

Answer (score 0):

if you build from source using Maven then you can override the artifact final name in the POM of this project

```
 <finalName>myJar</finalName>
```

If you run the mvn install manually then you have control of what you store into the Maven repository

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Comment: The `<finalName>..</finalName>` will only change the name for the `target` directory...

Comment: Is there a way to also change the name of the jars getting into <other-module>/target/<app>/WEB-INF/lib/ as dependencies?